# How to make button visible after more than one checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table and it has checkbox what I want is when more than two checkboxes are selected my button should be visible and vice versa

**JavaScript** Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 1) {
    $("#checkerButton").show();
  } else {
    $("#checkerButton").hide();
  }
});
```

The **`.PHP`** File:

```
<div>
  <form action="" method="POST" id="checkerDeleter">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Selected" class="btn btn-danger" id="checkerButton" />
  </form>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Check</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Discount</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <!--<td>Category</td>-->
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php while($row = $resultallproducts->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleter[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" /></td>
          <td class="hide"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><textarea name="desc"><?php echo $row['product_desc'] ?></textarea></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="discount" value="<?php echo $row['product_discount']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['product_quantity']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Update" /></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete" /></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

first it is disabled but when I click on two checkboxes nothing happens :\

Comment: I can't find #checkerButton in html..where is?

Comment: You only ever doing this check on the domReady,.. I think you might want to attach that check to the checkbox change event..

Comment: @JacopoBrovida there it is now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use change event to check if 2 or more checkbox are checked

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 1) 
        {
            $("#checkerButton").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#checkerButton").hide();
        }
  
       $("input:checkbox").on("change",function(){
         
         if($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 1){
            $("#checkerButton").show();
         }else{
            $("#checkerButton").hide();
         }
       }); 
  
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="checkerDeleter">
            <input  type="submit" value="Delete Selected" class="btn btn-danger" id="checkerButton"/>
        </form>
    </div>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Check</td>   
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Quantity</td>
                        <!--<td>Category</td>-->
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleter[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td class="hide"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><textarea name="desc"><?php echo $row['product_desc'] ?></textarea></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="discount" value="<?php echo $row['product_discount']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['product_quantity']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Update"/></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete"/></td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleter[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td class="hide"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><textarea name="desc"><?php echo $row['product_desc'] ?></textarea></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="discount" value="<?php echo $row['product_discount']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['product_quantity']; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Update"/></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    </form>
                 
                </tbody>
            </table>
```